# Multiple regression/correlation analysis, large dataset:ways, tools

Tags: r, correlation, multiple-regression, python, scikit-learn

I've got a large "clean" dataset (800 MB), containing 210k rows and 320 columns. There is 2 discrete string-type columns, others are numeric. One of such numeric columns is selected as depended variable. My goal is to find subset of columns that has the most deep influence to that depended variable.

The question is: what is the best ways, algorighms and tools to do it quickly? I've heard only about a scikit-learn in Python, and some tools in R, but I also need an examples, and have problem with reading the dataset to memory in Python/Pandas and R without chunking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a server or a PC with a large amount of RAM in order to handle your dataset. There are companies, such as Amazon, that sells online server accounts.

As for a model/algorithm, a good starting point might be the Random Forests (RF) algorithm (see the original paper here http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324, for me it's free of charge). You can find an implementation of RF on the randomForest package of R.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a large data set. This should all fit into RAM even on an average desktop, say with 8-16GB RAM. The large data sets will have millions of rows and tens of GB size files. Your should even be loadable into Excel without much trouble.